# UILabel and NSLinkAttributeName: Link is not clickable

Tags: ios7, uilabel, nsurl, nsattributedstring, clickable

I want to use attributed strings with `NSLinkAttributeName` to create clickable links inside a `UILabel` instance within my iOS 7 project, which is now finally possible without using external libraries.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

NSDictionary *attr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          url, NSLinkAttributeName, nil];
```

Applying the attribute on a string displays the text as blue & underlined, but nothing happens on click/tap. User interaction is enabled for the label.
Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I can answer my own question now:
I am using `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` now. I have formatted the `UITextView` to look and behave like my labels and added:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
textView.editable = NO;
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
textView.delegate = self;
```

Don't forget to set the delegate, you have to implement `UITextViewDelegate`! Now we implement the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)url inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
     return YES;
}
```

This automatically opens the provided the `NSURL`-instance from the attributed string in my question on click/tap.

Remember: This works on iOS 7 only, for legacy support you need external libraries

**UPDATE:**

Making the `UITextView`s behave just like labels was a total mess in the end and i stumbled upon some hideous iOS-behaviours. I ended up using the [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) library which is simply great and allowed me to use labels instead of `UITextView`s.

Comment: The .textContainer is key here. I swapped my labels out for textviews and had the links working but it was throwing off the layout and look.

Comment: Surely you mean UITextViewDelegate not UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: yeah of course, I have corrected the mistake - thanks.

Comment: @max.mustermann: Can you elaborate on what issues led you to abandon this approach?

Comment: @WCByrne can you explain that? I would like to do the same. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ricardo, just pointed out that setting the `textView.textContainer.---` values are the key to getting UITextViews to layout like UILabels. That is to say, those values, adjust the padding of the text in the TextView; setting them to zero give you the look of a UILabel with the functionality of a UITextView.

Comment: +1 @WCByrne, ABSOLUTELY make sure you set the .textContainer values . This ensured that UITableViewAutomaticDimension worked properly for my dynamic height cells.