# NSAttributedString with a URL not working

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, nsattributedstring

In a swift iOS app, I have set a UILabel with an NSAttributedString on it.
The AttributedString contains a URL set with

```
[NSLinkAttributeName:NSURL(string:urlStr)!].
```

All appears fine, meaning that the URL is clearly set as such, but when I tap it nothing happens.

Is there something I should do to make the URL work as one would expect (i.e fire Safari)?

I tried the following but it had no effect at all.

```
theLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Not getting what you want to do. If you want clickable control then why did not you put button instead of the label?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854506/uilabel-and-nslinkattributename-link-is-not-clickable

Comment: Well. I have a text on a label and it would be convenient just to have part of the text to be clickable without having to make a specific component for that. I am looking for the simplest way.

Comment: Use UITextView and follow @Undeph answer

Answer (score 4):

NSLinkAttribute is not working with UILabel as the handler method will respond to UItextViewDelegate Only.

You can either use. [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) or can go with Replacing your UILabel with UITextView. After replacing the same use

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

And don't forget to check for Detection and Behaviour property.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
var str: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Google")
        str.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "http://www.google.com", range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length))
        yourLabel.attributedText = str
```

This is not directly about the question but just to clarify, UITextField and `UILabel` does not support opening URLs. If you want to use `UILabel` with links you can check [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel).

Also you should set dataDetectorTypes value of your `UITextView` to `UIDataDetectorTypeLink` or `UIDataDetectorTypeAll` to open URLs when clicked. Or you can use delegate method as suggested in the comments.

Comment: use this library https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel @Michel