# Attach click action to portion of UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel with attributed string in it. I want to attach click/tap event to one word in it. Is there a way to do it? The solution of using UIView instead of UILabel, as suggested at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854506/uilabel-and-nslinkattributename-link-is-not-clickable), does not fit to my case. I'm asking specifically about UILabel. 
Preferable not to use external libraries.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-in-ios

Comment: a label doesnt expose its storage IIRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it isnt publicly possible right now because the UILabel as opposed to a UITextView doesnt expose the internal text storage object

either switch to a textview or add a UIButton? ;)